# JavaScript OOP - constructor

Tags: javascript

I'm new with OOP, I need little help to fix the application. I appreciate your help.

1.Output: the new student Object { id: "1", name: "John", surname: "Doe", points: "90" }
Should be: new student Ojbect {[student1],[student2]}
2. method DidPass,
how can I use check if the user id is matching with the studentInfoArray id? :\

```js
let studentInfoArray = [];

function Student(id, name, surname, points, DidPass){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.points = points;
    DidPass = function(){
    if(this.points < 50){
        return false;
    }else if(this.points > 50){
        return true;
    }
    } 
}


// Ask user to enter 'Create' or 'Check status' or 'Exit
function userChoice(){
    let userInput = prompt('\t Enter your choice \n \'Create\'  \t  New Student \n \'Check\'  \t  Check status \n \'Exit\'  \t\t  Exit App ');
    if(userInput == ''){
        counter = 0
        alert('The input is invalid');
        while(counter < 5){
            userInput = prompt('\t Enter your choice \n \'Create\'  \t  New Student \n \'Check\'  \t  Check status \n \'Exit\'  \t\t  Exit App ');
            alert(`The input is invalid, for the ${counter} time`);
            counter++;
        }
        if (counter == 5){
            alert('Your IP address is banned! You enter invalid input 6 times');
        }
    }else{
        switch(userInput){
            case 'create':
                alert('You choose to create student');
                //let stundentInfo = prompt('please enter your id, name,surname,points').split(',');
                //studentInfoArray.push(stundentInfo);
                studentInputCheck = prompt('Please enter your id, name, surname, points').split(','); // Ask user to enter info
                if(studentInputCheck == ''){ // condition if the prompt is empty
                    alert('The field is empty!?');
                    counter = 0;
                    while (counter < 3){ // we are giving the user 3 chances to enter valid input
                        studentInputCheck = prompt('Please enter your id, name, surname, points').split(',');
                        alert(`${counter} times. Be careful!`);
                        counter++;
                    }
                    if(counter == 3){ // if he doesnt enter valid input, we will kick him out of the app
                        alert('Your IP address is banned! You enter invalid input 4 times');
                        break;
                    }
                }else{ // if the Input is valid
                    studentInfoArray = studentInputCheck;
                    //studentInfoArray.push(studentInputCheck); like this studentInfoArray [0] has another array of the input :\
                    //console.log('array',studentInfoArray);
                    console.log(studentInfoArray);
                    let id = studentInfoArray[0];
                    let name = studentInfoArray[1];
                    let surname = studentInfoArray[2];
                    let points = studentInfoArray[studentInfoArray.length - 1]; //  [3] :|'
                    let studentINFO = [id,name,surname,points];

                    console.log('new', studentINFO);
                    console.log('All info',id,name,surname,points) // we have all the elements from the array

                    let student = new Student(id,name,surname,points); // construct new student
                    
                    console.log('the new student',student); // We have new array 
                    break
                }

            case 'check':
                alert('You choose to check status!');

                if(student[0] = studentInfoArray[0]){
                    alert('you are ok');
                    console.log(student.DidPass());
                    
                }else{
                    alert('your id doesnt exists');
                    console.log(student.DidPass());
                }          
                break
            case 'exit':
                alert('Cao');
                break;
        }
    }
}

userChoice();
```

Comment: `DidPass = function(){…}` does not create an object method. I suggest you look into how to create prototype methods.

Comment: `=` is the asignment operator, `==` is the comparison operator.